# Neither piecewise continuous function nor continuous function examples

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

After I read the definition of piecewise continuous function, it seems like either function is piecewise continuous or continuous. Can a function be neither of these two?

Comment: The classic example is $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational and $1$ if $x$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a function like $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x\in\mathbb Q\\ 0, x\not\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}$?

Comment: Is it because there is infinite number of ending points?

Comment: That's the idea.  Technically, for given $x$  and $\epsilon\lt1$, there are points arbitrarily close by such that $\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid\gt\epsilon$.